calculating a virtual raster slope layer using gdal
I'm sure someone already created this but my searches came up to nothing.
While using huge DEMs I find myself constantly creating Slope and Aspect duplicates.
I'd like to calculate those on the fly with a vrt file.
Is there a way of doing it using the gdaldem slope function?
When asked, the bing co-pilot suggested embedding this function:


<PixelFunctionType>custom_slope</PixelFunctionType>
<PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
<PixelFunctionCode>
            <![CDATA[
            import numpy as np

            def custom_slope(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize, raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
                xres = gt[1]
                yres = -gt[5]
                dzdx = (in_ar[0, 1:-1, 2:] - in_ar[0, 1:-1, :-2]) / (2 * xres)
                dzdy = (in_ar[0, 2:, 1:-1] - in_ar[0, :-2, 1:-1]) / (2 * yres)
                slope = np.sqrt(dzdx**2 + dzdy**2)
                out_ar[0, 1:-1, 1:-1] = np.arctan(slope) * 180 / np.pi
            ]]>
</PixelFunctionCode>



This includes changing some security settings, plus I guess gdal slope will run faster. Right?
